# Embedding images in Birt

Tags: eclipse-plugin, birt

I have to embed an image in Birt. But I don't want the image to be displayed in the report itself. I want the image to be Embedded in the PDF that I will be able to export only. I tried searching for a way to do this, but was unsuccessful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the image to **display** in the PDF export?

Answer (score 3):

To add an image to your report that will only be displayed when exported to PDF:

- Add the image to the desired location in the report.
- Select the image in the Layout view, then select the Visibility options in the Properties tab of the Property Editor:

  - Check the `Hide Element` checkbox;
  - Select the `For specific outputs...` option;

    - Check the specific output checkboxes for all formats **except** PDF

If you now save and run the amended report, you should find that the image is only displayed when exported to PDF.